# How can I get to redirect the recipient view after sending using c#?

Tags: docusignapi

I need to redirect to the recipient view after sending the document. I am able to get to the send view. I am able to get to the recipient view. But I am unable to make them work together.

Thanks
Bill

Answer (score 2):

Do I understand correctly that you're using embedded/captive Sending to allow the Sender to create/send the Envelope from within your application, and then want to immediately (upon sending of the envelope) open the Envelope for the Sender to Sign (i.e., Sender is also first signer)?

If that correctly describes what you're trying to achieve, the key to achieving it is using the **returnUrl** property for both the "POST Sender View" operation (when retrieving the URL that will launch the Embedded Sending view) and for the "POST Recipient View" operation (when retreiving the URL that launches the signing view).

1. Submit "POST Sender View" API request, specifying **returnUrl** = "http://www.yourApp.com/yourAppsReturnPage.aspx" -- this is where DocuSign will redirect to once the embedded Envelope Sending process is complete.
2. Code logic in your App's return page (http://www.yourApp.com/yourAppsReturnPage.aspx) to examine the value of the **event** parameter that DocuSign appends to the URL to specify the outcome of the Sending session.  (See page 172 of the REST API Guide [https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/rest-api-guide-v2.pdf] for a list of possible values of the **event** parameter.)
3. If the value of the **event** parameter is "send" this means that the Envelope was sent successfully.  If so, you can immediately issue a "POST Recipient View" request to get the URL that can be used to launch the sender's (i.e., first signer's) signing session. When you receive the response, you can immediately redirect the browser to the URL specified in the response, to launch the Sender's signing session.

Doing things as outlined here should present a seamless user experience for the user -- they finish sending the Envelope, and then their Envelope is immediately thereafter presented for signing within the browser.

Note -- You'll specify the **returnUrl** property in the "POST Recipient View" request as well, to tell DocuSign where to redirect once the Signing Session is complete. And, just like I described earlier -- your returnUrl page should examine the value of the **event** parameter to determine the outcome of the embedded signing session, so that it can respond appropriately. See page 170 of the REST API guide for a list of possible values for the **event** parameter when using embedded/captive signing.